# Modifiers in solidity

Tags: solidity

I am writing a contract where a funcion can be modified by the `valid user` or the `admin`.

Can I use two modifiers in the same function and the function can be accessed if either one of the modifiers succeed?

Or is there any way to make the admin bypass all modifiers and conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a simple modifier that checks both conditions.

```
modifier onlyAllowedUsers {
  require(validUser[msg.sender] || admin == msg.sender, "Error Message");
  _;
}
```

Supposing validUser is a mapping that maps addresses to booleans.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved it. Forgot to update it.